# Difference between rm executable >>dev/null and rm executable

Tags: command-line, rm, redirect

What is the difference between

```
rm executable
```

and

```
rm executable >>dev/null
```

I had the later statement in a `Makefile` and changed it to the first one. I had the impression that nothing changed.

Comment: Do you mean `rm executable &> /dev/null` instead? What you wrote should not work.

Comment: If something is piped to /dev/null it means any messages that would be seen in the terminal are not shown since they are piped no to the ouput but to nirvana the /dev/null

Comment: @heemayl Only if you do not omit the slash at the beginning of /dev/null. And I think rm will mainly produce messages on STDERR, so that would not be very useful.

Comment: `rm a >>dev/null` **appends** only **stdout** to a **local** file called **`null`** in a local directory called **`dev`**. What you probably meant is `rm a &> /dev/null` which redirects both stdout and stderr to the special character device /dev/null.

Comment: What you *really* should have is `-rm -f a`, probably.  Throwing away error messages is a bad idea, *especially* when you're not telling Make to ignore exit status.

Comment: @cat Please don't suggest the use of bashisms.  `rm a > /dev/null 2>&1` is the portable construct.

Comment: @zwol You're right, but bash is the default and widely used for Ubuntu so I figure it's fine *in  a comment*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rm executable
```

simply deletes the file `executable` from the current directory.

```
rm executable &> /dev/null
```

does the same, but it runs the command with output and error streams redirected to the special file `/dev/null`.

That means you will not see any messages in the terminal. The `/dev/null` file they are redirected to instead is a virtual character device which simply swallows all incoming data like a black hole.

Output redirection to `/dev/null` like this is often used in scripts where you don't want the user to see possible output of the contained commands.

Comment: But don't black holes emit radiation !?! :D

Comment: @geek1011 /dev/null usually doesn't. However, quoting Wikipedia: "The April Fool's, 1995 issue of the German magazine c't reported on an enhanced /dev/null chip that would efficiently dispose of the incoming data by converting it to a flicker on an internal glowing LED."

Answer (score 4):

This append line to `/dev/null` only means that all output is omitted or better to say send directly into the data nirvana (or void, or bottomless pit). So the only thing that could change is that if this command runs into an error that you will see output for it on the screen.

Comment: Nirvana? I... don't think you know what that word means :P I've never heard /dev/null called that, but "void" or "bottomless pit" might be better

Comment: @cat nirvana, from Skt. nirvana-s: "extinction, disappearance" (of the individual soul into the universal), lit. "to blow out, a blowing out" ("not transitively, but as a fire ceases to draw;" a literal Latinization would be de-spiration), from nis-, nir- "out" + va "to blow". So still a perfect fit :), but I'll add your suggestions into my answer.

Comment: "You don't know the definition of that word," I tell someone on the internet, not having actually recently looked up that word. For some reason I thought it means "heaven" or "peaceful place" whatever, I dunno

Comment: It can be used in both ways, well however were not here to discuss etymology of words :) you're not wrong to think it means freedom of pain (or heaven) but can be used as it is as well for the opposite. It even has depending on the religion it is used in different meanings as well, see [its wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana).